# I'm unable to launch my unreal game with error code 5

Tags: compiler-errors, unreal-engine4, launching-application

So I've set up a test game and added some widgets and c++ to it, and when I play my game everything works fine. However when I try and launch my game i get this error:

LogPlayLevel: Error:   ERROR: Unable to instantiate module 'UnrealEd': Unable to instantiate UnrealEd module for non-editor targets.

and i just don't know how to solve it. I've tried to find answers however it doesn't seem like anyone else gets this.

I'm still new to unreal so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you referencing the UnrealEd or any other editor only module in your build file?

Comment: @Rotem No, I'm Not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a fix that worked for me.

The .uproject file contains a list of additional dependencies, for example:

```
"AdditionalDependencies": [
            "Engine",
            "UnrealEd",
            "UMGEditor",
            "UMG"
        ]
```

From those four i had to remove both UnrealEd and UMGEditor which depends on the former.

I didn't reproduce this situation in a clean project, but I suspect it to be either a widget editor bug, or the change occured while building with incorrect headers.

Comment: Thanks so much Ernestynian, just completed my first build after doing this

Comment: I have the same issue but I dont have UnrealEd as dependencies. What happenes If I remove UMGEditor? I think its important in UMG.

Comment: @SaadAnees I have not used UE4 a lot since then so take my advice with a grain of salt. This could be a new issue as you are probably using a much newer build. If your error is exactly the same I would look for UnrealEd it in the project's source files, such as *.Build.cs. I don't know what would happen if you remove UMGEditor, so my suggestion would be to make a backup of your project and try building without this dependency. Otherwise please create a separate question if your issue is (even slightly) different + I recommend official Discord channel as it seems to have a lot of actve users.